# Convert Two column data frame to occurrence matrix in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

Hi all I have a csv file which contains data as the format below

```
A   a
A   b
B   f
B   g
B   e
B   h
C   d
C   e
C   f
```

The first column contains items second column contains available feature from feature vector=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
I want to convert this to occurence matrix look like below

```
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
A   1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
B   0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1
C   0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this using pandas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is another way to do it using `pd.get_dummies()`.

```
import pandas as pd

# your data
# =======================
df

  col1 col2
0    A    a
1    A    b
2    B    f
3    B    g
4    B    e
5    B    h
6    C    d
7    C    e
8    C    f

# processing
# ===================================
pd.get_dummies(df.col2).groupby(df.col1).apply(max)

      a  b  d  e  f  g  h
col1                     
A     1  1  0  0  0  0  0
B     0  0  0  1  1  1  1
C     0  0  1  1  1  0  0
```

Comment: Shouldn't the apply function use a "sum" for completeness to record multiple values of a particular pair? It will also give the correct answer in the above case.

Answer (score 8):

Unclear if your data has a typo or not but you can [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas.crosstab) for this:

```
In [95]:
pd.crosstab(index=df['A'], columns = df['a'])

Out[95]:
a  b  d  e  f  g  h
A                  
A  1  0  0  0  0  0
B  0  0  1  1  1  1
C  0  1  1  1  0  0
```

In your sample data your second column has value `a` as the name of that column but in your expected output it's in the column as a value

**EDIT**

OK I fixed your input data so it generates the correct result:

```
In [98]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""A   a
A   b
B   f
B   g
B   e
B   h
C   d
C   e
C   f"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+', header=None, names=['A','a'])
df

Out[98]:
   A  a
0  A  a
1  A  b
2  B  f
3  B  g
4  B  e
5  B  h
6  C  d
7  C  e
8  C  f

In [99]:
ct = pd.crosstab(index=df['A'], columns = df['a'])
ct

Out[99]:
a  a  b  d  e  f  g  h
A                     
A  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
B  0  0  0  1  1  1  1
C  0  0  1  1  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach yields the same result in a scipy sparse coo matrix much faster

```py
from scipy import sparse

df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype("category")
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype("category")
df['ones'] = 1
user_items = sparse.coo_matrix((df.ones.astype(float),
                               (df.col1.cat.codes,
                                df.col2.cat.codes)))
```