# Cooccurence matrix from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

## Problem

I have a pandas dataframe, and I need count how many rows are there where each unique entry in the dataframe occurs within the same row of each other entry.

---

## Related but different posts

- [Co-occurrence Matrix from list of words in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814452/co-occurrence-matrix-from-list-of-words-in-python):
  Similar question to mine, but does not start with a dataframe. Most answers use iterations. I hope a better solution exists in Pandas.
- [Constructing a co-occurrence matrix in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574257/constructing-a-co-occurrence-matrix-in-python-pandas):
  This already starts with a dataframe where there are only 0 and 1 in the body (I guess representing the actual values?) but not the actual values.
- [Convert Two column data frame to occurrence matrix in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518937/convert-two-column-data-frame-to-occurrence-matrix-in-pandas):
  This post assumes there are two columns only, which is rather restrictive for the case discussed here

---

## Reproducible Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

The dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'b': ['B', 'C', 'B', 'B'],
                   'c': ['C', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
                   'd': ['B', 'D', 'B', 'A']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

ie:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    | a   | b   | c   | d   |
|----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
|  0 | A   | B   | C   | B   |
|  1 | A   | C   | A   | D   |
|  2 | B   | B   | C   | B   |
|  3 | B   | B   | A   | A   |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

<sub>(Printed using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885295/8565438).)</sub>

---

## What I have tried

I have tried to use the [code from answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42814963/8565438), & substituting these variables:

```
document = [list(each) for each in df.values]
names = list(np.unique(df.values))
```

It gave the wrong results:

```
  A B C D
A 4 6 3 2
B 6 10 5 0
C 3 5 0 1
D 2 0 1 0
```

It is based on iteratations, so I would hope for a better solution.

---

## Expected Output

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    |   A |   B |   C |   D |
|----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
| A  | nan |   2 |   2 |   1 |
| B  |   2 | nan |   2 |   0 |
| C  |   2 |   2 | nan |   1 |
| D  |   1 |   0 |   1 | nan |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

There are `2` rows where `A` & `B` both appears, so the value in the cell row `A` column `B` is `2`.
There are `2` rows where `A` & `C` both appears, so the value in the cell row `A` column `C` is `2`.

---

## Question

**How can I get this row-wise cooccurence matrix easily in Pandas?** It would be great if I didn't have to loop through the values.

---

<sub>([pandas.Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) might be some use, I haven't managed to make it work yet.)</sub>

Comment: You have two row contain `AC` :-)

Comment: Oh yep, true! Corrected! :) (sorry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WE can do `stack` then `get_dummies` and `dot` then value

```
s=df.stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).ne(0).astype(int)
s=s.T.dot(s).astype(float)
np.fill_diagonal(s.values, np.nan)
s
Out[33]: 
     A    B    C    D
A  NaN  2.0  2.0  1.0
B  2.0  NaN  2.0  0.0
C  2.0  2.0  NaN  1.0
D  1.0  0.0  1.0  NaN
```